# How to fix writer's thought muddledness?

Tags: technique, organization, plot

Honestly my problem here is that I've been on writing hiatus for like...a year and half. Apart from writing small stories here and there, I haven't really taken on a story to a larger scale in a long time. There's several factors which caused it, but I'm spare you the details.

Either  way, I recently got in the inspired creative mood that I'm been trying to regain control of again for awhile now, and I have this one story idea (sort of, not sure if I like it yet or not). The problem is, all my ideas for it are so muddle and jumbled into chaos in my head, that I can't even think  straight to *start* thinking of where to begin. And I know someone's probably just going to suggest that I "sit down and think about it and write anything about it that comes to mind". Listen, that doesn't work for me. I can't even force my mind or body to do that. It's like grating nails on chalkboards for me right now. Maybe once I'm not so *rusty* at getting my thoughts in my head so organized I could do that, but not in my current state.

And for the record, how I *use* to get my thoughts in order was simple: I didn't. I've never needed to do this before, so I lack the skills and knowledge of methods to help myself. In the past, whenever I had an idea, I just instantly *knew* it in my head. Even if I didn't know where it was heading, I did have it in order enough to run with it. My God, it feels like I have cotton in my head right now. Please help!

Comment: Jenna, welcome to Writers, but I'm afraid questions like this aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange sites, which are a little different from most discussion boards. I'm going to close this for now, but if you can narrow this down to a more specific, answerable question, we'll consider reopening.